# Shell time command source code?

Tags: linux, time, open-source

Where can I find the `time` bash utility source code? Is there a website that allows to search for this code?

Comment: If you are talking about the `bash` built-in, then it is obviously a part of the `bash` source; otherwise it's a GNU utility, not _bash utility_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `time` command is from the [GNU project](http://www.gnu.org/), so all of the source code is available there.

Specifically, you are probably looking for this: http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/time/

Comment: This is probably the wrong `time`. OP might want the bash internal command.

Comment: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/time.git

Answer (score 4):

The `time` command in Bash is built-in, so it should be found in the [GNU Bash source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/).